# WPF/Forms: Creating a new control programmatically that can have events

Tags: c#, wpf, events, forms, controls

I wanted to know if it was possible to create a control from another control and which this new control could process certain events.

For example, lets say we have a Button that once it is clicked on will create a ComboBox. Could this new ComboBox be capable of processing a certain event such as a SelectionChanged event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure thing. Simply provide an event handler and hook it up to the event:

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Button button = new Button();
    button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(button_Click);
}

void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox combo = new ComboBox();
    combo.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(combo_SelectionChanged);
}

void combo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do your work here.
}
```

Comment: So if you add, for example, 10 new ComboBoxes you will able to handle the events of each and every one of them?

Comment: Oh and will you be able to make them do different things?

Comment: Can you handle the events of each and every one? Definitely. The code I have provided will handle the SelectionChanged event for every single combo-box you add.

Can you make them do different things? Sure, but there will need to be some underlying data that you can get at to differentiate between the combo-boxes. What do you have in mind?

Comment: What I have in mind is a TabControl that has button in it that allows to create new tabs. Each tab would be used by the user to write some information.